# How do I get my intent to call my fulfilment on DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I must be missing something because my intent is never calling my fulfillment script.

I created an intent, let's say it is called `xyz`. It is simple, just has some phrases it can be called by.

I created the JavaScript under fulfillment, and it has a function called `abc()` that should be called. I also added:

```
intentMap.set('xyz', abc);
```

But my fulfillment is never called when I test the phrases of `xyz`, I just get `Sorry, project name isn't responding right now. Please try again soon.`

I don't even see the logs on the first lines of my script there.

The first few lines look like this:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
```

So I'm assuming that means I should be seeing those `console.log` lines but I don't see them. Does that mean that I have neglected to link my intent with my fulfillment? How do I do that?

Edit: Here is the screenshot of the intent:

[image]

This is the code:

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const { Card, Suggestion } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
  function testIntent(agent) {
    const conv = agent.conv();
    agent.tell('this is a test');
  }
  // // Uncomment and edit to make your own intent handler
  // // uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);`
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  // function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
  //   agent.add(`This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!`);
  //   agent.add(new Card({
  //       title: `Title: this is a card title`,
  //       imageUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png',
  //       text: `This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! `,
  //       buttonText: 'This is a button',
  //       buttonUrl: 'https://assistant.google.com/'
  //     })
  //   );
  //   agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quick Reply`));
  //   agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion`));
  //   agent.setContext({ name: 'weather', lifespan: 2, parameters: { city: 'Rome' }});
  // }

  // // Uncomment and edit to make your own Google Assistant intent handler
  // // uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);`
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  // function googleAssistantHandler(agent) {
  //   let conv = agent.conv(); // Get Actions on Google library conv instance
  //   conv.ask('Hello from the Actions on Google client library!') // Use Actions on Google library
  //   agent.add(conv); // Add Actions on Google library responses to your agent's response
  // }
  // // See https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-actions-library-nodejs
  // // for a complete Dialogflow fulfillment library Actions on Google client library v2 integration sample

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('test intent', testIntent);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: It would help if you updated your question to include a screen shot of the entire "xyz" Intent, so we can see how it is configured, and the Fulfillment screen, so we can see how it is configured. You say you don't see the debugging in the logs - do you see anything in the logs? If so, seeing the logs could also help.

Comment: You have this tagged "google-assistant-sdk". Is this being run for Actions on Google?

Comment: Have you enabled Fulfillment for your intent?

Comment: I've added the screenshot and code. It is called `test intent`. I'm using DialogFlow, came there from the actions console, I guess assistant sdk might be wrong? And yes I enabled the fulfillment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `testIntent()` handler function is calling `agent.tell()`, which isn't a valid method.

I suspect you meant to call `agent.add()`

Comment: Ok, but should I see `console.log(....` on the logs? I'll try what you suggested in a bit.

Comment: You should. But you didn't post any logs at all, so I can't guide you on that.

Comment: You are totally right, that fixed it. Thank you. Kinda disappointed on the error handling, such a simple mistake. I had copied that code from somewhere else, maybe an old api or something.

Comment: The error logs should have reported that error to you as well.